# How to block uipangesturerecognizer in uitableviewcell when table view scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

i have table view with custom cell with structure (ContentView->UIView(name Regulator))

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panRecognized:)];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.Regulator addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

when i'm scrolling in tableView cell under my finger moving too with panRecognizer. I need to scroll in cell only when tableview stops scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Swift Solutions:
Below is the my code snippet and which worked very well in swift 3.0

//This method helped me stopped up/down pangesture of UITableviewCell and allow only vertical scroll

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview!)
        if abs(translation.x) > abs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: you are my personal hero! :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if table view is scrolling:

```
if (!tableView.isDragging && !tableView.isDecelerating)
{
   // the table is *not* scrolling implement you logic here 
}
```

Comment: "panRecognized" method defined in cell, not in viewcontroller. Cell don't know about tableView.

Comment: add this in your panRecognized: method to check if table view is being scrolled first.

Comment: when you define your panRecognizer in your cellForRow AtIndexPath method you also define the method to be called when this gesture is detected. In your case this is -(void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture method. Is that correct? If it is simple insert this if statement and you implementation inside it. Your view controller has a reference to your table view. You don't need this reference in your cell

Comment: no, not in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Method defined in cell. Cell manages itself.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. So, inside your `panRecognized` method, you can check,

```
-(void) panRecognized :(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
    if([tableView isDecelerating] == FALSE)
    {
          //Do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: "panRecognized" method defined in cell, not in viewcontroller. Cell don't know about tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You should always implement this sort of code in your viewcontroller instead of in your UITableViewCell class.

This is a little bit hacky approach and I wouldn't use it, but should do the trick for you

First add private instance to a tableView object

```
@implementation MyCustomCell
{
  UITableView *tblView;
}
```

In your code here:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panRecognized:)];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.Regulator addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Add this line of code:

```
tblView = [[self superview]superview];
```

Then in your panRecognized method you can perform the following check:

```
if(!tblView.isDragging && !tblView.isDecelerating)
{
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Once again I would recommend doing this in your viewController instead. Happy coding!